# Alternate Turtlebot Configurations

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone know of methods for powering and recharging *all* components from
the iRobot Create on a [Turtlebot](http://turtlebot.com/)? I'd like to get a Turtlebot, but it's hacky power system and inability to auto-recharge, despite the Create's builtin auto-recharge mechanism, is a huge non-starter.

Specifically, would it be practical to replace the laptop/netbook with a more efficient [Raspberry Pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org) or [OLinuXino](https://www.olimex.com/Products/OLinuXino/), which only need 5V?

Similarly, has anyone tried replacing the Microsoft Kinect (requiring 12V) with the much smaller and more energy efficient [Asus Xtion](http://www.asus.com/Multimedia/Xtion_PRO_LIVE/), which only needs 5V over USB?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54840/alternate-turtlebot-configurations/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2013-02-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If it helps, the [TurtleBot2](http://clearpathrobotics.com/turtlebot_2) has a much better power system and can auto-recharge.

Other than that:

1. Yes, it is possible to replace the netbook with a single-board computer. We do not ship with one by default because it's a higher barrier for entry for new Linux & ROS users, but it's quite possible. However, if you're working with Kinect data, we suggest something faster than a Raspberry Pi (even if you're only using pointcloud_to_laserscan and transmitting the scan). I know that @Tully (among others) got ROS running on a RasPi, but it can't do much on that board.
2. Yes, the Xtion is known to work. It's not the "default" sensor for TurtleBots because the Kinect is cheaper and we're really trying to make these robots as economical as possible.

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2013-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2013-02-14**:
On a side note, why is the Kinect sensor mounted to the rear of the platform where it has to "look through" the bot's interior? Wouldn't it have better visibility, and free up all that interior space, if mounted more towards the front?

**Comment by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) on 2013-02-14**:
The Kinect depth sensor has a minimum effective range of ~0.5 m and a limited horizontal field of view. Pulling it back means that you're able to get closer to objects and see a wider area in front of the robot.